# Swap Items between DataGrids via Drag'n Drop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling

I've already searched for quite a while, but I am unable to find an answer for my specific question. I have a WPF application with several DataGrids, each containing 7 objects of a custom type, which I called `DataGridString` containing the properties `UnitType` and `Quantity`

I would like to be able to use drag and drop to switch items between the DataGrids, so that when I drag a selected item from DataGrid1 to DataGrid2, that item gets inserted to DataGrid2's drop mouse position and DataGrid1 receives the item that was previously at the newly placed item in DataGrid2.

My app looks like this:

[image]

I would like to be able, to, let's say, select row 3 in the first, blue table (Hero 1: `UnitType`: `Royal Griffin`, `Quantity`: `2`) and drop the item at row four of the second, red table (Hero 2, `UnitType`: `(EMPTY)`, `Quantity`: `0`).

What I've tried so far is using the event types `MouseMove`, `DragEnter`, `Drop` in the following way:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridUnitList1"
          FontWeight="Regular"
          FontSize="10"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          Grid.RowSpan="1"
          Grid.Row="3"
          Grid.Column="4"
          Margin="3, 3, 3, 3"
          Padding="0"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          AreRowDetailsFrozen="True"   
          FrozenColumnCount="2"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          AllowDrop="True"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          MouseMove="DataGridUnitList_OnMouseMove"
          DragEnter="DataGridUnitList_OnDragEnter"
          Drop="DataGridUnitList_OnDrop"
          CanUserAddRows="True"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Type" Binding="{Binding UnitName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<DataGrid Name="DataGridUnitList2"
          FontWeight="Regular"
          FontSize="10"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          Grid.RowSpan="1"
          Grid.Row="3"
          Grid.Column="4"
          Margin="3, 3, 3, 3"
          Padding="0"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          AreRowDetailsFrozen="True"   
          FrozenColumnCount="2"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          AllowDrop="True"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          MouseMove="DataGridUnitList_OnMouseMove"
          DragEnter="DataGridUnitList_OnDragEnter"
          Drop="DataGridUnitList_OnDrop"
          CanUserAddRows="True"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Type" Binding="{Binding UnitName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

...
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
        private void DataGridUnitList_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                DataGridString unit = (DataGridString)dataGrid.SelectedItem;

                DataObject dragData = new DataObject("dragData", unit);
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dataGrid, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }

        private void DataGridUnitList_OnDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }

        private void DataGridUnitList_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("dragData"))
            {
                DataGridString unit = e.Data.GetData("dragData") as DataGridString;
                DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
                dataGrid.Items.Add(unit);
            }
        }
```

I am aware that the code displayed cannot work as intended, as I currently merely add the new data item and do neither remove, nor insert anything new into the other table. I was thinking about triggering an event in `DataGridUnitList_OnDrop` when I place the item with a drop, so that the table I dragged the item from gets sent the item from the "drop table".

Is this possible? Are there alternatives to my failed approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` and `Drop` events for the `DataGridRow` containers by removing and adding items from the source collections. Here is an example that should get you well started:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGridUnitList1.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<DataGridString> { ... };
        DataGridUnitList2.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<DataGridString> { ... };
    }

    private void DataGridRow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)sender;
            DataGridString unit = (DataGridString)row.DataContext;

            DataObject dragData = new DataObject("dragData", unit);
            DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(row);
            dragData.SetData("itemsSource", dataGrid.ItemsSource);
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dataGrid, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

    private void DataGridRow_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("dragData"))
        {
            DataGridString unitToAdd = e.Data.GetData("dragData") as DataGridString;

            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)sender;
            DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(row);
            ObservableCollection<DataGridString> targetCollection = dataGrid.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<DataGridString>;
            if (!targetCollection.Contains(unitToAdd))
            {
                DataGridString unitToRemove = row.DataContext as DataGridString;

                ObservableCollection<DataGridString> sourceCollection = e.Data.GetData("itemsSource") as ObservableCollection<DataGridString>;

                int index = targetCollection.IndexOf(unitToRemove);
                if (index == -1)
                    index = 0;
                sourceCollection.Remove(unitToAdd);
                targetCollection.Insert(index, unitToAdd);
            }
        }
    }

    private static T FindVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

        if (parent == null)
            return null;

        var parentT = parent as T;
        return parentT ?? FindVisualParent<T>(parent);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridRow_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
            <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="DataGridRow_Drop" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>

        <DataGrid Name="DataGridUnitList1"
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Type" Binding="{Binding UnitName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>


        <DataGrid Name="DataGridUnitList2"
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Type" Binding="{Binding UnitName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```